# JavaScript Regex match returns null or undefined

Tags: javascript, regex, firefox

```
var url_pattern = new RegExp("(?:http| https)://(www.|.*)someurlhere[.]com/\d\d\d\d/\d\d/\d\d/.*/", "i");
var url=window.location; //or could be document.URL both don't work
url.match(url_pattern);
```

why does it return null, or undefined but when i throw the Regex into a check it works perfect and i just want to make sure the URL matches

Comment: It's worth noting that window.location is actually an object. There are a number of available and useful properties defined on Location. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

Comment: i added toString() to the object, and it is still giving me a NULL for the return

Comment: @PeterWagenet - using window.location in a context that expects a string automatically calls toString() on it which gives you the full URL.  Probably better to use the `.href` proeprty if that's what you want, but either will work in most circumstances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have issues with your slashes and an extra space before `https` and some period characters not escaped properly either.

When using the `new RegExp("string")` format, you have to double escape any backslash.  It's much easier to use the `/regexhere/` syntax because you don't have to double escape the backslash used in so many regex rules.

Also, a string has a regex method called `.match()`.  The regex itself has a method called .`test()` or `.exec()`.  I would suggest this:

```
var url_pattern = /(?:http|https):\/\/(www\.|.*)someurlhere\.com\/\d\d\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\/.*\//i;
window.location.href.match(url_pattern);
```

If you want to stay with the other way of declaring it, you would escape every backslash like this:

```
var url_pattern = new RegExp("(?:http|https)://(www\\.|.*)someurlhere[.]com/\\d\\d\\d\\d/\\d\\d/\\d\\d/.*/", "i");
window.location.href.match(url_pattern);
```

Comment: You failed to properly escape your slashes. This will generate a syntax error.

Comment: @PeterWagenet - where?  In the first pattern, only forward slashes need to be escaped.  In the second pattern, only backslashes need to be escaped.

Comment: @jfriend00 yea at the first one throws illegal character but the 2nd one works like a charm thanks

Comment: @italiano40 - I fixed the first one.  It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vB9ZD/.

Comment: @jfriend00 ok just switched that one in and it works good thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While you should consider using the `/regexhere/` syntax suggested by jfriend00, you can also make your RegExp work with the RegExp.new syntax. The problem is that you're within a string so any backslashes you have are considered to be escape character for the string itself, not for the RegExp. To work around this issue you should use a double backslash. Your RegExp should be changed to:

```js
new RegExp("/(?:http|https)://(www.|.*)someurlhere[.]com/\\d\\d\d\\d/\\d\\d/\\d\\d/.*/", "i");`
```

You may also want to make some other changes to your RegExp as well. For instance, I would suggest using `\\.` (again note the double escape for use within a string) to match periods instead of using `[.]`.